# How to get double loot and XP from a Pokestop?

Tags: pokemon-go

While spinning PokeStops, I was able to get double loot (7-8 items) and double XP (100 XP) twice. However, I do not understand whether I did something special for this and I cannot find any information on this matter.

Does anyone know how to get these double loot and XP from spinning a PokeStop?

Update: faced this again. Images are below. This was the first pokestop for a long time.

[image][image]

Comment: Maybe it was delayed from a previous Pokéstop. If you get XP (or items) within a short time it gets shown as sum of both. So with 2 stops in a row it says 100 XP instead of 2x 50 XP.

Comment: Perhaps. I will try to notice this if I face this again.

Comment: Did you get that Jynx??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found that every 10th unique Pokéstop spun will give you 6+ items, 100 XP and an egg (if space permits), but you have to follow a specific pattern. Basically, if you continue to spin unique Pokéstops, every 10th stop will give you the bonus.  Someone test this out for me.

Comment: I have had a chance to check this assumption at last and I can confirm that definitely this is the case!

Comment: I don't think the egg is guaranteed. Every tenth unique Pokéstop spun should definitely give you 6+ items, and 100 XP. It will give you an egg based on normal Pokéstop mechanics.

Answer (score 10):

Loot is just random. sometimes i get 3 items, other 7. XP in my personal experience is related to the number of items you get. 100xp with more than 5

source: hours and hours of playing

Comment: This seems to be the case. Cannot find any specific actions that lead to this double stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you get multiple xp gains in a short time, the game will only display the total once. It may be that.

Look in your history journal if you want to double check.

Comment: is not the time it take to gain xp. if you are in the pokemon menu, evolving and so, when you return to the main window, you see all the xp gained in one value

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible causes for this "double loot and XP" phenomenon:

- **Sheer Luck**
  Pokestops have a chance to randomly spit out double loot. Perhaps you were just lucky and managed to hit the right random number.
- **Unique Spins**
  If you're in a new area and spin 10 (untouched by you) Pokestops within 30 minutes, the 10th Stop will automatically grant you 6 or more items, an egg (if you have inventory room), and double EXP from a single swipe.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up getting more when I spun it twice.... I "spin" it again before it finishes the first spin and it works for me...