# What are my chances to get anything from Pokestops?

Tags: pokemon-go

The items you get from pokestops are variable. Sometimes you get 3, sometimes up to 7...

Is there a breakdown of how that is generated?

Like how it decides to give you once 5 pokeballs, then 1 ultraball + 2 potions, etc.

Comment: the algorithm is not revealed. just random. but when you get more than 5 items you also get double xp. see: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275628/how-to-get-double-loot-and-xp-from-a-pokestop?rq=1

Comment: I've heard that if you hit 10 unique Pokestops in a row in a certain amount of time, the 10th one gives you a higher yield. That is why I run in a loop, not up and back. My sample size is small and it's not always the 10th, but around the 10th I get lots of supplies. (but this is `pure speculation`).

Comment: I guess I'm looking for the algorithm... and that question will stay open until the algorithm is figured out

Comment: Don't have time to type this into an answer, but see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4w6s8t/10th_pokestop_hack_bonus/) on reddit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I am simply translating your comment section into an answer and adding a bit.  The algorithm is random (though I have no source) when it comes to Pokestops.  Some times you will get 2 Pokeballs and 1 Potion, and other times you will get 1 Pokeball, 1 Greatball, an Egg, and a Potion.  There is an unverified rumor going around [@Kevin L] about hitting your 10th unique Pokestop.  They say every 10th unique Pokestop you spin you will receive a bonus - 50 extra experience and multiple extra items (still random).  I hope this helps sum things up.

Comment: From what I've read and experienced, it must be 10 different Pokéstops in less than 30 minutes.